# Getting Data from MySQL Database without Refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have been trying to get the names of users from the database using jQuery and php but I've had no luck so far. It manages to post value in the text field to the name.php file but i can't echo out the names linked with the username in the database.

The HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Retail Management Application</title>
    </head> 
    <body>             
        Name: <input type="text" id="username">
         <input type="submit" id="username-submit" value="Grab">
            <div id="username-data"></div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/global.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The global.js file:

```
 $('input#username-submit').on('click', function() {
    var username = $('input#username').val();

    if ($.trim(username) != '') {
        $.post('ajax/name.php', {username: username}, function(data){  
            $('div#username-data').text(data);
        });
    };
});
```

name.php:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['username']) === true && empty($_POST['username']) === false) {

    require '../db/connect.php';

    $query = mysqli_query("
            SELECT `username`.`name` 
            FROM `users` 
            WHERE `users` . `username` ='". mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username'])). "'
            ");
    /*  $query = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `username`.`name` FROM users 
                                            WHERE `users` . `username` 
                                            = '". mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']))."'"); */
    echo (mysqli_num_rows($query) !== 0) ?  mysql_result($query, 0, 'name') : 'Name not found!';
    //tenary operator.
    }
?>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root") 
                    or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));     
    mysqli_select_db("retail_management_db");           
?>
```

Comment: So do you get `Name not found` or nothing at all or  what exactly ?

Comment: You can't mix `mysql_X` and `mysqli_X` functions. If you're using `mysqli`, you have to use `mysqli_fetch_array` to get the row of results.

Comment: adeneo, I get nothing sent back, not even "Name not found" just a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

You must use mysqli_fetch_array to get the result and then echo it.

Put this under your mysql query

```
if($query)
{
while($query_result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
//This returns an array of the fetched values
$name = $query_result['name'];
}
echo $name;
}
else
{
echo "Query Failed";
}
```

Name.php then becomes

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['username']) === true && empty($_POST['username']) === false) {

require '../db/connect.php';




                   $query = mysqli_query("
                    SELECT `username`.`name` 
                    FROM `users` 
                    WHERE `users` . `username` ='". mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username'])). "'
                    ");

if($query)
    {
    while($query_result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
    //This returns an array of the fetched values
    $name = $query_result['name'];
    echo $name;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Query Failed";
    }


/*  $query = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `username`.`name` FROM users 
                                        WHERE `users` . `username` 
                                        = '". mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']))."'"); */




    //You should not use mysqli with mysql
    echo (mysqli_num_rows($query) !== 0) ?  mysql_result($query, 0, 'name') : 'Name not found!';


    //tenary operator.
}
?>
```

**Edited Area**
Don't use Mysql functions with Mysqli

Your name.php now should be

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['username']) === true && empty($_POST['username']) === false) {

    require '../db/connect.php';




                       $query = mysqli_query("
                        SELECT `username`.`name` 
                        FROM `users` 
                        WHERE `users` . `username` ='". mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username'])). "'
                        ");

    if($query)
        {
        //We check if the returned rows are at least one
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
        {
        while($query_result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
        //This returns an array of the fetched values
        $name = $query_result['name'];
        echo $name;
        }
        }
        else
        {
        echo mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username'])) . "Name not Found";
        }
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Query Failed";
        }


    /*  $query = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `username`.`name` FROM users 
                                            WHERE `users` . `username` 
                                            = '". mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']))."'"); */




        //You should not use **mysqli** with **mysql**
        /*echo (**mysqli_num_rows**($query) !== 0) ?  **mysql_result**($query, 0, 'name') : 'Name not found!';*/


        //tenary operator.
    }
    ?>
```

**Edit**

Use this temporarily as your html file Check if name.php actually echoes anything If it prints anything then the problem is from your js **Make sure the action on the form is linked to the correct name.php file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Retail Management Application</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
      <form action = 'name.php' method = 'post'>             
        Name: <input type="text" id="username">
         <input type="submit" id="username-submit" value="Grab">
        </form>
            <div id="username-data"></div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/global.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Chuksy, it seems it still not returning anything, the post works but its not sending the data back to the global.js script.

Comment: Check the Edit I made on the answer